# Chinese characters not showing up properly in strings.xml

Tags: android, eclipse, localization, character, chinese-locale

I have created an android application and have a Chinese version of my strings.xml. The Chinese characters I copied into the new string.xml file do not show up properly. They show up as the "square" characters you see when a language is not rendered properly. How do I display Chinese characters in my application.

When I run the application in the Emulator using the Chinese language setting, it displays properly.

Comment: The emulator and device are running on same android version? Actually, they started supporting other languages from 4.1. So you might face issues on the earlier versions if you dont use your own font file (.ttf or .otf). This is the case for most of the languages. But I am not sure for chinese.

Comment: the characters are displayed properly when i run the emulator. What I;'m asking is why the chinese characters are shown as blank squares in the strings.xml

Comment: So you mean, it works on the emulator and device. But it's not displayed properly on the XML. Right? In that case, I think the problem is with your text editor. you can try opening the strings.xml in a text editor that supports chinese characters. May be Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

For eclipse IDE.

At project explorer > Right click to `string.xml` > Properties > Resources > Text file Encoding. Should be UTF-8.

If not I suggest to convert related files to UTF-8 via Notepad++ and also change hole eclipse settings to support/use UTF-8.

If I am not mistaken to change eclipse settings go to Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text file Encoding > UTF-8

**Edit:** Reference for eclipse encoding: http://www.chasingdaydreams.com/2010/04/using-eclipse-with-chinese-or-other-foreign-characters/

Comment: i have tried changing the text file encoding to utf-8 but still the same

Comment: you have to change both the settings at the eclipse and the document's encoding (that with notepad++)... It usually works.

Comment: I can't think anything else that may be faulty... close and reopen the file? restart eclipse? or ask google https://www.google.gr/search?q=eclipse+encoding+for+chinise (added a reference to my post)